# How to write a for loop that deletes row data in R

Tags: r, dataframe, loops

I have a large csv file which I imported into R as a data frame. To avoid manually editing my CSV file, I am attempting to complete it in R using a loop. The code is as follows:

```
  if(Practice$zt[x] >= 0.0 &  Practice$zt[x] <= 2.5) {
    
     print(Practice$zt[x])
   
  }
  if(Practice$zt[x] >= 12.0 & Practice$zt[x] <= 14.5) {
    
    print(Practice$zt[x])
  } 
  
}
```

Essentially, I want my code to go through the dataframe starting at row 1 and check if the zt column is either between 0-2 or 12-14. Any number not in these ranges will delete the whole row, but I can't get my loop to correctly run through the code. I keep receiving this error:

```
In if (Practice$zt[x] >= 0 & Practice$zt[x] <= 2.5) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ila suggestion is right. Check tidyverse and some book like https://r4ds.had.co.nz/ and your skills will improve dramatically. R is a vectorial language, you don't iterate dataframes or vectors, and for sure not with for loops. If you want to iterate, take a look at purrr.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to want to learn about the `dplyr` package; `filter()` will do what you want in a much simpler way

```
install.packages("dplyr") #You only need to run this once
library(dplyr) #You'll need to run this every time you start R

Practice <- Practice %>%
  filter((zt >= 0 & zt <= 2) | (zt >= 12 & zt <= 14))
```

As for why your code isn't working, it probably has to do with what you're defining `x` as

Answer (score 0):

If statements only take **one** TRUE or FALSE value, a vector with multiple values at the same time (for example c(FALSE, TRUE)) will create ambiguity. To address this problem, base R has `ifelse()` function that works with vectorized conditions. On the other hand, using `&&` is safer with traditional if statements. This code will ilustrate the what i'm saying.

```r
library(tidyverse)

#notice this
seq(1:5) < 3 & seq(1:5) < 5
#> [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
seq(1:5) < 3 && seq(1:5) < 5
#> [1] TRUE

#inside an if statement
if (seq(1:5) < 3 & seq(1:5) < 5){}
#> Warning in if (seq(1:5) < 3 & seq(1:5) < 5) {: the condition has length > 1 and
#> only the first element will be used
#> NULL



#vectorized if
ifelse(iris$Sepal.Width >= 4 & iris$Sepal.Width <= 5, iris$Sepal.Width, NA)
#>   [1]  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA 4.0 4.4  NA  NA
#>  [19]  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA 4.1 4.2  NA  NA
#>  [37]  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
#>  [55]  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
#>  [73]  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
#>  [91]  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
#> [109]  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
#> [127]  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
#> [145]  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA

ifelse(iris$Sepal.Width >= 4 & iris$Sepal.Width <= 5, iris$Sepal.Width, NA) %>%
    keep(~ !is.na(.x))
#> [1] 4.0 4.4 4.1 4.2

#finally notice this
ifelse(iris$Sepal.Width >= 4 && iris$Sepal.Width <= 5, iris$Sepal.Width, NA)
#> [1] NA
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Finally, i think that @ila answer is the overall better approach in the long run but it can get some time getting used to dplyr's synthax. Totally worth it tho.